# Is there any way to receive email notifications when someone accepts/merges my pull requests?

Tags: github

Is there any way to receive email notifications when someone accepts/merges my pull requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github doesn't provide for such an option yet in their [accounts/notifications page](https://github.com/account/notifications).

[image]

perhaps you can contact the repo admin to setup a [service hook](https://github.com/github/github-services)

Answer (score 0):

This does work in the meantime:

> We have just added notifications when a Pull Request is merged and when an Issue/Pull Request is closed or reopened.

Source: [Github blog](https://github.com/blog/1307-new-close-and-merge-notifications)